# Best practice to declaring counter variables in nested for loops in C99

Tags: c, for-loop, declaration, c99, definition

I'm asking which is the best practice between this two implementation:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
    for ( int j = 0; j < 5; j++ )
        ...some code here...

...other code...

for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
    for ( int j = 0; j < 5; j++ )
        ...some code here...
```

or this one:

```
beginning of function/main
int i,j;

...some code...

for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
    for ( j = 0; j < 5; j++ )
        ...some code here...

...other code...

for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
    for ( j = 0; j < 5; j++ )
        ...some code here...
```

In other words is it better:

1. declaring counter loops one time for all and defining them inside each loop
2. or declaring them every time?

Thank you

EDIT:
My question is:
***Is it better to perform N declarations (and definitions) for 2 variables or 2 declarations and N definitions ?***

EDIT2:
Ok now I understand. I didn't know that declaration only affect the compilation and not the execution ( I saw assembly language of C99 compiled source file). So there's no difference and Lundin's answer shows the standard to use.

Comment: IMO a variable should be declared closest to its intended use. You'd be surprised how little the generated code for these two styles is different. Which is better is purely a matter of opinion.

Comment: OT: What you call "declaring" a variable, is actually *defining* it. What you call "defining" is actually *initializing* or *assigning to* the variable.

Comment: @StoryTeller: I think this is a fact, rather than an opinion. Or "In My Dogmatic Opionion"? ;-)

Comment: @Bathsheba - The generated code is fact :) The many discussions I had with veteran programmers in my firm over lunch, is plenty opinionated (and boy did I get an earful for why the C90 way is better...).

Comment: Also OT: You present two code-snippets in your question, and two alternatives you ask about. The problem is that the first code-snippet is representing the *second* alternative, and the second snippet is for the *first* alternative. This might seem somewhat confusing.

Comment: I don't understand. Does declaring need more asm (cpu cycle) operation than defining?

Comment: @princio: Did you back up that assumption by checking the generated assembly by your compiler will full optimisation?

Comment: As a guy using C89 (old architecture, old toolchain) I wish I could declare the variables in the loop directly. If I were you I wouldn't even consider doing something else.

Comment: A *definition* tells the compiler "this variable exists here and now, please make sure there is memory allocated for it". A *declaration* tells the compiler "this variable exists *somewhere* in the code". It really have nothing to do with performance of the program itself.

Comment: Voted to re-open. This is no more opinion-based then writing C code without using any line breaks.

Comment: Ok now I understand. I didn't know that declaration only affect the compilation and not the execution ( I saw assembly language of C99 compiled source file). So there's no difference and Lundin's answer shows the standard to use.

Answer (score 3):

This is actually not opinion-based, but there exists a widely recognized industry standard:

**Reduce the scope of a local variable as much as possible.**

This is the very reason why C++ and C99 allow iterator declarations inside the loop itself. Meaning that the first version is better, period.

*However*, the second version has to be used if you need to know the iterator values after the loop has finished, or if you need C90 backwards-compatibility.

Comment: Only in iterator (for loop) this should be allowed. code like `printf("a");printf("b"); int c = 10; printf("%d", c);` is ugly.

Comment: @tilz0R yes, you should be using `puts()` instead in first two cases. :D

Comment: @tilz0R - I totally agree. You definitely should not write it all in a single line.

Comment: @StoryTeller it is a thin line between fool and smart person. #justsayin

Comment: @tilz0R - There's also a very thick line between understanding sarcasm and not

Comment: @SouravGhosh Using `puts("a");` is functionally different than `printf("a");`.  `puts()` is not a matching alternative in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Always keep the scope of variables as tight as possible.

Your second option leaks `i` and `j` unnecessarily into the surrounding scope, so is not to be preferred.

Comment: It leaks? What?

Comment: @tilz0R: leak = end up where they shoudn't. For the avoidance of doubt, we're **not** talking about memory leaks here!

Comment: Usually this is called "namespace pollution".

Comment: @Lundin: In C++, namespace pollution is an entirely different thing.