# What is the good practice to declare loop variables?

Tags: c, loops, variables, scope

In a block of code, I need to get an input from the user and print it right away. I'm a bit confused with good practice between these two snippets.

Snippet #1:

```
int i;
while(){
    scanf("%d", &i);
    printf("%d", i);
}
```

> I'm using the variable *i* **only within the loop**. So, should I declare and use it within the loop itself to maintain good practice of using scopes?

If I do the same,

Snippet #2:

```
while(){
    int i;
    scanf("%d", &i);
    printf("%d", i);
}
```

> the variable *i* is declared on every iteration of the loop! These re-declarations consume more processing power and re-allocation of memory again and again

Which approach is better and why?

Comment: This always depends on your requirement. If you want to count the number of iterations of the while loop, you will declare i outside the loop, if you want i to reset with every iteration, you will define it inside the loop

Comment: Say, I want to reset with every iteration and declared inside. That will take more processing and re-allocation everytime! is that good?

Comment: In any case, you are changing the value of the Variable with `scanf`. Usually, the two snippets you have will have the same overhead (means the performance will be the same). As for which one is better, I personally will go for the second one as I would like to use the variable within the scope of the scope of the loop (Unless for any reason I require the latest value form the loop outside of that scope).

Comment: Okay, in that case, may I know what will happen? After every iteration, the memory is destroyed and re allocated again and again (or) same memory is used?

Comment: The variable is placed on the stack which is almost free, and almost certainly occupies exactly the same spot in memory throughout the loop no matter if you place it outside or inside the loop. https://godbolt.org/g/y7tPqP  Worry about things like making your program correct and choosing efficient algorithms, not individual variables. Once your program works you can profile it and decide if it needs to be changed.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46543170/best-practice-to-declaring-counter-variables-in-nested-for-loops-in-c99

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said:

> > the variable i is declared on every iteration of the loop! These re-declarations consume more processing power and re-allocation of memory again and again

This is an invalid assumption on your part. The C compiler will calculate the total memory the function needs and allocate for that usage up front. For local variables, that allocation is actually just a shift of a pointer.

To illustrate, if I have a function:

```
void a_function () {
    extern int x, n1, n2;

    while (--n1) {
        int i;
        scanf("%d", &i);
        x += i;
    }

    while (--n2) {
        int i, j;
        scanf("%d %d", &i, &j);
        x += i + j;
    }
}
```

The compiler will allocate space for 2 integers on entry into the function (or none, if it decides it can do everything in registers).

Comment: the two integers that you mentioned are int i, j within two loops, right?

Comment: @SathyamoorthyR Pretend the `extern` line is outside the function. First loop wants one integer, second loop wants two. Compiler generates code that reserves space for two.